# Could the mount namespace API effectively be made redundant? What obstacles would there be?

Tags: mount, linux-kernel, namespace

1. You can still access files and directories in a different mount namespace, *if* you have a reference to them.  However, currently you can't manipulate (or even list) the mounts of a mount namespace, if it is not the namespace you are running in.
2. Detached mounts (`umount -l`) are considered to have no mount namespace and therefore you are not allowed to manipulate them (or list sub-mounts).

Is the limitation in point 1 (or point 2) essential to the namespace API, e.g. for security?  Is it relied on by existing software?

If not, would it be difficult to remove the limitation in point 2 (and point 1) from the Linux code?  That is, what would be the main obstacles to doing so?

Motivation: If you could create detached mount trees, you could `chroot` into them, and I think mount namespaces would be mostly redundant.  Although they would still provide some convenience/uniformity with other types of Linux namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you could build a detached mount tree, you could `chroot` into it, and I think mount namespaces would be mostly redundant.  Although they would still provide some convenience/uniformity with other types of Linux namespace.

I think there's (at least) one important point I missed.

One of the features of namespaces is that they are associated with a user namespace.  A user namespace isolates the "super-user" capabilites, such as CAP_SYS_ADMIN and CAP_NET_RAW.  E.g. CAP_NET_RAW can allow access to the raw network packets on net devices - if they are owned by a network namespace, which belongs to your userns.

CAP_SYS_ADMIN is allowing you to manipulate the mount namespace which belongs to your userns.  The current limit might be tighter than it strictly needs to be, but you need some limit.  Tying mount trees to a namespace is necessary so that user namespaces can isolate CAP_MOUNT.

I guess there isn't much point to implement some alternative to mount namespaces, that would not work as well with user namespaces.